# How can I populate a user field via a plugin?

Tags: plugin-development, users

I have a plugin that listens for the `users.onSaveUser`. So when users register, an account is created, and I am creating an entry that will contain extended profile information. I am attempting to create a user field on that newly created entry to relate the entry back to the user account.

**MyPlugin.php**

```
$entry = new EntryModel();
$entry->sectionId = 16;
$entry->typeId = 1;
$entry->enabled = false;
$entry->authorId = $user->id;

$entry->getContent()->title = craft()->request->getPost('firstName') . ' ' . craft()->request->getPost('lastName');

// userAccount is the handle of the user field.
$entry->setContent(['fields' => ['userAccount' => $user->id]]);  // nope.
$entry->setContentFromPost(['userAccount' => $user->id]);        // nope.

...

craft()->entries->saveEntry($entry);
```

Everything is coming across except the user field. I'm not sure what the field needs/is looking for to set it's value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relational fields are always stored as arrays, even if you are limiting them to only one entry so this should work:

```
$entry->setContentFromPost(['userAccount' => array($user->id)]);
```

Comment: That was it. I knew I was close - just wasn't sure how to send the right "stuff" to set the field. Thank you!